# Input type range - oninput change label - use javascript "if" to change specific value

Tags: javascript, input, range, label

I've got a input-range slider which changes the label on slide.

Now, when range value is = 5, label text changes to "5 år".
I want to say: If label text is "31 år" change text to "Infinity" for example.

So all numbers from 5-30 "år" is ok but "31 år" should be changed to something else / a different value.

```
<label id="af">30 år</label>
<input id="afid" name="afdrag" type="range" max="31" min="5" value="30" oninput="var str = document.getElementById('af').innerHTML = this.value + ' år'">
```

Comment: change the oninput to `var str = document.getElementById('af').innerHTML = this.value<31?this.value+' år':'infinity'` it will work

Comment: It worked! Thank you SO much!

Answer (score 0):

Just add a ternary operator to check for condition.

```
var str = document.getElementById('af').innerHTML = this.value<31?this.value+' år':'infinity
```

Here is the demo

```html
<label id="af">30 år</label>
<input id="afid" name="afdrag" type="range" max="31" min="5" value="30" oninput="var str = document.getElementById('af').innerHTML = this.value<31?this.value+' år':'infinity'">
```